# Understanding Pinescript NZ function usage in this code

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, pine-script-v4

Please help me confirm my understanding of the following Pinescript function which implements a Kalman filter. I have included some comments in the code with my understanding/questions on what the code is trying to accomplish. Thanks!

```
kalman(x, g) =>
    //x is a moving average (MA) and g is a constant
    kf = 0.0 
    dk = x - nz(kf[1], x) //Calculate the difference between current bar's MA value and 
                          //MA value at the previous bar?
    smooth = nz(kf[1], x) + dk * math.sqrt(g * 2) //Is nz(kf[1], x) equal to the previous 
                                                  //bar's MA value?
    velo = 0.0
    velo := nz(velo[1], 0) + g * dk //Not sure what nz(velo[1], 0) is supposed to model. 
                                    //Is that building velo by adding velo's value on the 
                                    //previous bar to g*dk?
    kf := smooth + velo
```

Answer (score 2):

`nz()` will replace `na` values with the given value.

`nz(kf[1], x)` will check if `kf[1]` (`kf`'s value on the previous bar) is `na`. If it is `na`, it will replace it with `x`.

Comment: Thanks! What I don't get is what will happen across the timeframe. I am trying to grasp the logic behind dk and velo calculations. On the first bar, kf[1]=NaN, therefore nz(kf[1], x) will be calculated to x(bar1) and dk will be 0. On the second bar, what is the value of kf[1]? Is it NaN again? In that case dk will be 0 across the time period. Regarding velo, is nz(velo[1], 0) trying to add the previous value of velo to g*dk to calculate the current value of velo?